# Timeout error C++

Tags: c++, jdoodle

```
#include <iostream>
// #include <conio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int choice;
double temp, result;
 std::cout <<"Enter temprature";
std::cin>>temp;
 std::cout<<"Enter number between 1 or 2";
std::cin>>choice;
switch (choice){
case 1 : 
    result = (5*temp /9) - 32;
     std::cout<<"answer is" <<result<<"C \n";
    break;
case 2 :
    result = (9/5*temp) + 32;
     std::cout <<"answer" <<result<<"F";
    break;
default :  std::cout<<"Wrong number";
}
return 0;
}
```

I'm using this code for basic conversion (switch practice) and there comes Timeout error. I'm new to cpp so please don't mind if you find this easy.

Also, How can i use conio.h functions like getch() in this program?
I'm facing this error :

```
Enter temprature


Timeout -  Some common reasons for Timeout 
Your Program may have a endless loop
```

Comment: I believe the formula you are using is incorrect.

Comment: I'm more bothered about the compilation of the program.

Comment: I'm not submitting it for anything. I'm learning switch loops and basic c++

Comment: What compiler are you using? Here is an [example](https://repl.it/repls/MistyComplicatedStag) in which it compiles correctly, with no changes. There is no such thing as a timeout error in any code that isn't timed... (which most contests do). As far as conio.h goes, It is recommended that you do *not* use that, since it is nonstandard (only available on Windows)

Comment: tell once again, what TIMEOUT ERROR? What is exactly Your problem?

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you're using an online compiler and didn't provide any input.

Comment: I'm using GCC 7.2.0 compiler @ArnavBorborah and I've edited the question providing the error

Comment: @Neha _did_ you prove any input?

Comment: How will I provide input when the error is there just after I run it.

Comment: Timeout errors are not a thing for "normal" applications - whatever platform you are running this on has to provide some way for you to provide input. Since we do not know what platform that is we could only guess how to do it

Comment: @Neha some online compilers make you predefine the inputs for the application (See my answer). If you want a better _interactive_ compiler, something like [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/), or [repl.it/languages/cpp11](https://www.repl.it/languages/cpp11) should better suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, Finally found the error. It seems that you are using [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-compiler-c++), and didn't provide any input to stdin! This is quite simple to solve. Simply click the box that says `Stdin Inputs...`, and write on the first line the input for the first prompt, and on the second the input for the second prompt. Here is a sample screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The only problem with this is that every single output is on the same line, so you may want to add a few newlines in your code.

As a second solution, you could turn interactive mode on (The button right above the stdin inputs), which would actually ask you for the input while running the program. This solution may suit your needs better, since it makes more sense.

As far as `conio.h` goes, You will be unable to use functions from that header (Which is good, since they are nonstandard), unless you are working locally on a Windows computer.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! I tried to upvote this question, but I'm not privileged to do that.

Comment: pretty overwhelming answer.

Comment: It's good if it works. The only thing I want to tell you is to be more specific with your problem in the future, such as by telling which website/compiler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles in MSVS 2015, and seems to work.

This:

> `result = (5*temp /9) - 32;`

is not the right formula.  It should be

```
result = 5 * (temp - 32) / 9;
```

This:

> `result = (9/5*temp) + 32`;

suffers from integer overflow.  It should be:

```
result = (9.0 / 5 * temp) + 32;
```

or

```
result = (9 * temp / 5) + 32;
```

> How can i use conio.h functions like getch() in this program?

`conio.h` is not a standard header and `getch()` is not a standard function, so although you may be able to use them on some platforms they will not be available on others.

Comment: Well! that's not the main issue or my question about. It's about timeout error.

Comment: @Neha. You say you face an error, but 1. We don't know your compiler 2. We don't know the exact words in the error. You need to _give more information_. The only evident issue in your code is the wrong formula...

Comment: @SidS I'm not even priveledged to downvote you. Also, people downvoted my question and they doesn't even realize they are demoralising someone.

Comment: @SidS can you please delete your answer so that I can delete this question?

Comment: @SidS, the fact that you spent time solving somebody else's problem does not make you downvote-proof. Your answer does not solve the issue and is about something entirely different. The fact that the question is incomplete is another story, but you, my sir, should not think that solving a new problem you discovered makes you a holy entity

Comment: @Neha do not delete the question. Edit it in order to provide the complete error description and desired outcome. Read the comments below your question and ask additional questions about how to improve it there